# Adding a RAM section in linker file STM32

Tags: c, linker, embedded, stm32

I am trying very hard to understand how to use a linker file, but my brain is apparently not getting it at all.  I am using an STM32L476, which has two RAM regions, RAM and RAM2 (memory definition below).  I would like to put a buffer into RAM2, but there is no section for RAM2 in the default linker script that is generated by Cube.  Seems like a good exercise for me.  I really thought that the following would do the trick, where all I've added is the .sensor_buffer section:

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);    /* end of "RAM" Ram type memory */

_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200; /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400;    /* required amount of stack */

/* Memories definition */
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 96K
  RAM2    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x10000000,   LENGTH = 32K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 1024K
}

/* Sections */
SECTIONS
{
  .sensor_buffer :
  {
    KEEP(*(.sensor_buffer))
  } >RAM2
  
  /* The startup code into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM

  /* The program code and other data into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  .text :
  {
    ...
  } >RAM

  // Other Cube-generated sections here
}
```

However, this adds a .sensor_buffer section to an address that is not in RAM2.  From the .map file:

```
...
.igot.plt       0x0000000020000190        0x0 load address 0x000000000800f29c
 .igot.plt      0x0000000020000190        0x0 c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.6.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_1.5.0.202011040924/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/crtbegin.o

.sensor_buffer  0x0000000020000190     0x2000 load address 0x000000000800f29c
 .sensor_buffer
                0x0000000020000190     0x2000 Core/Src/main.o
                0x0000000020002190                . = ALIGN (0x4)

.bss            0x0000000020002190     0x1fb0 load address 0x000000000801129c
                0x0000000020002190                _sbss = .
                0x0000000020002190                __bss_start__ = _sbss
...
```

Can someone point out either where I went wrong here, and/or, even better, somewhere that I can work through some "easy" examples to get used to LD?  I really want to get this stuff, but the first steps are really brutal for me without any resources except a rather dense set of man pages.

**EDIT** Adding the code used to declare the buffer. In `main.c`, global scope:

```
static uint8_t data[DATA_BUFFERS][DATA_SIZE] __attribute__((section(".sensor_buffer")));
```

Comment: Could you please add the source code that defines the data to be placed on RAM2?

Comment: @Tagli Yes I can, find it in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error somewhere else. Maybe you simply do not use this linker script (you forgot to add or change the name in the command line)

I have compiled it and linked it without any problems with CubeIDE (I use 100 and 100 in the buffer declarations as I do not know the values of your macros  [100x100 = 0x2710])

```
.sensor_buffer  0x0000000010000000     0x2710
 *(.sensor_buffer)
 .sensor_buffer
                0x0000000010000000     0x2710 Core/Src/main.o

.isr_vector     0x0000000020000000        0x0
                0x0000000020000000                . = ALIGN (0x4)
```

Comment: This is generating code for an STM32L476?  This is the only project in my workspace, and the only thing I have changed from Cube generated code is the line in my edit, a call to an SAI receive function that fills the buffer (properly, I can see it filled with valid values), the section in STM32L476RGTX_RAM.ld, and two defines, one for DATA_SIZE (1024) and one for DATA_BUFFERS (2).  Is that what you did?  I'm CubeIDE 1.6.1

Comment: Also, so I was right to add what I did to SECTIONS?  Because that really almost shocks me.  And finally, any chance you have a source or advice for getting better at linker scripts?

Comment: Why are you using RAM for the code. It is not good

Comment: @TrivialCase By default xx_FLASH.ld script is used. So my bet was correct. You simply edit one linker script but use another :D.

Comment: Ah okay.  Why do I have a .sensor_buffer in my map file at all then?  I have no such entry in the STM32L476RGTX_FLASH.ld file - it is unmodified.

Comment: I also clearly don't understand what the use of the two files is either, any chance you would be kind enough to include that in your answer?

Comment: @TrivialCase Do not use the RAM one at all. Simply delete it. You will never need it

Comment: @TrivialCase if it is unmodified - modify it! If you do not you will never see any changes. I do not understand your comment

Comment: I modified it now and it worked, thank you!  I was wondering why I had a .sensor_buffer section in my .map file if I had never made any edits to STM32L476RGTX_FLASH.ld and STM32L476RGTX_RAM.ld is disregarded.

Comment: @TrivialCase Then upvote and accept the answer.